# Skyrim thieves guild

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished restoring the theives guild to its former glory and become the head master. I have heard that every fence near the ragged flaggon is suppossed to have 4000 gold but for me only tonilia has 4000 gold the other fences still only have 500-1000 gold. Is there any other quests related to this that I have to complete or did my game just glitch.

Answer (score 5):

[The fences](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants) will have increased gold based on how much you have [improved the guild](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29#Improving_the_Thieves_Guild).

> Fences originally only have 1000 merchant gold, but that can be increased to 1500, 2250, 3000, and then ultimately 4000 gold by [improving the guild](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29#Improving_the_Thieves_Guild).

Improving the guild includes doing the side-quests offered by Delvin and Vex.